# use \IfEqCase output as a numeric value

Tags: calculations, xstring

How can i use the output as a number

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{xstring}
\newcommand{\CableType}{N2XSY}
\newcommand{\Ksc}{
                        \IfEqCase{\CableType}{
                        {N2XSY}{90}
                        {N2XSYRY}{90}
                        {N2XSYBY}{90}
                        {NA2XSY}{90}
                        {NA2XSYRY}{90}
                        {NA2XSYBY}{90}
                                 }
                        }
\begin{document}
\fpeval{2*\Ksc}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe it would be time to consider answers to your [previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/530625/creating-lookup-table)?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `xstring` commands where you need expandability. You can do it with `expl3`, though.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,xfp}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_eq:NN \EqCase \str_case_e:nn
\ExplSyntaxOff

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\Ksc}{}{%
  \EqCase{\CableType}{
    {N2XSY}{90}
    {N2XSYRY}{90}
    {N2XSYBY}{90}
    {NA2XSY}{90}
    {NA2XSYRY}{90}
    {NA2XSYBY}{90}
  }%
}

\newcommand{\CableType}{N2XSY}

\begin{document}

\fpeval{2*\Ksc}

\end{document}
```